# Calling a JDialog from another project?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have application A that is a GUI for a company.
I am making another application (B) and need to mock application A.
I have done the mock as a seperate project and just tried to import my LoginDialog.
But when I call it its not possible why?
I have imported project B into my mocked project A the other project and added to my build path;

```
import com.bombardier.transport.se.gui.LoginFrame;
```

Then I try to call my loginFrame that is located in another project (B) :

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                LoginFrame loginDialog = new LoginFrame();
                loginDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

But it want me to create the loginDialog method in the application B and that the method .setVisible is undefind for this type.
Thats not want I want to do. I just wanna open te dialog.

Why cant I do like this. It feels like  I am trying to do something that you cant do right?

Comment: Are you sure `LoginFrame` is public?

Comment: _"when I call it its not possible why?"_ - Why is it not possible? What's the error say?

Comment: LoginFrame is a Frame or Dialog?

Comment: Dialog. The code i jsut a bit confusing. Since I just changed from Frame To Dialog without changeing the class name :-)

Comment: LoginFrame may contain dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Create a `public void open() {}` method in the `LoginFrame` and put `setVisible(true)` there!

Then call `loginFrame.open();`